# How to find a web element using an href attribute

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

It's pretty straight forward. I have a String which contains an href value. I want to find the web element on the page that contains that specific href. I am using:

```
String href = "http://www.bing.com/images?FORM=Z9LH";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='" + href + "']")).click()
```

If you inspect www.bing.com you can see that the first link "images" on the top left has the href value that I set here.
When I run, it says that there is no such element on the page. I feel like I am not using the correct "find by" option.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li#scpt0>a")).click();
```

Comment: I don't believe this one-liner would work. I need to be able to dynamically change the variable href and find the element on the page.

Comment: Yes, I have. In my code above I have it in sort of a loop where href will constantly change. Your one-liner does successfully click the images link though! (over and over in my loop in this case)

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do then.  Your question seems much bigger and more involved than what you have so far.

Comment: Well I have a small web scraper that will compile all the links href attributes on a web page into a list<string>. I then loop through those string values in the list and try to click each link. I'm having trouble locating each link that I've already found with the href attribute as a place holder. Maybe I could use link texts?

Comment: I think link text would work much better for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see my link appears as such:

```
href="/?scope=images&amp;FORM=Z9LH1"
```

Therefore you may try to change your `href` variable's value. (if you're using chrome to see the source code, be aware that what you see in the F12 console and what you see with `Ctrl+U` is different. The `Ctrl+U` one is usually wha web parser see, before executing any JS or making subqueries)

Also, be aware that search engines (google, bing...) usually don't like being parsed, and they will do what they can to make your job impossible: using JS, iframe, changing patterns...

Comment: Ah I see, I plan to use this for a different website but just for a quick debug I run it on google/bing. I figured they wouldn't like being scraped but the href attributes is something that shouldn't change. (I think?)

Comment: @user2038633: Well we already have two different `href` linking to the same page, `&amp;` could be replaced by `&`, etc... Google changes the `href` value with JS when you click on it. I heard that in order to make their website harder to parse facebook returns a random page template that renders the same. That one might be a legend, but all in all you should probably do your test on a website that won't try to ruin them :)